# How to determine if the iPhone 6+ (plus) is in Standard or Zoom mode

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

I'm trying to determine if the iPhone 6+ is in standard or zoom mode and I can't find any API's that help determine this, so far the only thing that is indicating which mode the phone is in is the `nativeScale`

```
if ([UIScreen mainScreen].nativeScale == 3.0) {
    // its in the simulator
} else if ([UIScreen mainScreen].nativeScale == 2.880000) {
    // its an iPhone 6+ in zoom mode
} else if ([UIScreen mainScreen].nativeScale == 2.6086956521739131) {
    // its an iPhone 6+ in standard mode
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to know. Zoom mode will just use your layout for iPhone 5s.

Comment: But what's wrong with using the scale?

Comment: Nothing strictly wrong w/using scale, it just feels a little 'seat of the pants', I'd prefer if there were a more strict way to tell.

Comment: @AaronBrager In zoom mode its behaving more like the 6 than the 5S

Comment: In theory I 100% agree that using autolayout and coding for adaptive layout is the way to go, down in the trenches of existing code bases sometimes you gotta make some less attractive decisions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just checking the `bounds` (not `nativeBounds`) of the screen? IIRC, in zoom mode the bounds will be `{375, 667}` but in regular mode they are `{414, 736}`.

But yes, as mentioned in the comments.. if you are using AutoLayout, your app should "just" be able to adjust itself correctly and you shouldn't need to know.

Answer (score 0):

//you can check it from here

```
CGFloat screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
    NSLog(@"screnn width is ----<%f",screenWidth);



                       or


self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];


NSLog(@"screnn width is ----<%f",self.window.frame.size.width);
NSLog(@"screnn width is ----<%f",[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
```